# How to scrape ebay listing ID from attribute with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to edit my code to scrape the ebay listing ID of several listings. Right now, it scrapes the listing title and price. I can't figure out how to scrape only the listing id number from the iid. Below is the ebay html:

```
<div class="lvpic pic img left" iid="234387305971">
    <div class="lvpicinner full-width picW">
    <a href="https://www.ebay.com/itm/234387305971?hash=item36929275f3:g:jfYAAOSw0Wdh6wrb" class="img imgWr2"><img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/jfYAAOSw0Wdh6wrb/s-l225.jpg" class="img" alt="Item image"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I read that iid is an attribute so I tried:

```
listing_id = item.select_one('div[iid]')
```

That gave me the whole code of the div class as above.

Then, from searching I tried:

```
listing_id = [tag['iid'] for tag in item.select_one('div[iid]')]
```

But that gave the error, TypeError: string indices must be integers.

How do I go about only getting 234387305971? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """<div class="lvpic pic img left" iid="234387305971">
    <div class="lvpicinner full-width picW">
    <a href="https://www.ebay.com/itm/234387305971?hash=item36929275f3:g:jfYAAOSw0Wdh6wrb" class="img imgWr2"><img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/jfYAAOSw0Wdh6wrb/s-l225.jpg" class="img" alt="Item image"></a>
    </div>
    </div>"""

listing_id = [
    tag['iid'] for tag in
    BeautifulSoup(sample, "lxml").find_all("div", class_="lvpic pic img left")
]
print(listing_id)
```

Output:

```
['234387305971']
```

If you wan to *print* the `ids` use one of the following:

```py
for id_ in listing_id:
    print(id_)

print(listing_id[0])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This worked. Is there a way to get rid of the ['   ']  so that the output is just 234387305971?

Comment: Of course - use: `for id in listing_id: print(id)` (wth proper indentation).